# Git Windows Client denies me permission to Sync/push changes to my own repository

Tags: windows, github, permissions, fork, push

I have two repositories, one that I created, and one that I forked from ocotocat/Spoon-Knife.  I can push commits to the first, but not to Spoon-Knife.

I forked ocotocat/Spoon-Knife, then cloned it to my desktop, then edited one file, then committed, and on Sync (push), it fails with "It seems you do not have permissions to push to this repository".

I tried to add myself as a collaborator, but it says "cannot own owner as a collaborator" so I am pretty sure I should have permission.  As an owner.

How do I push these changes using the GitHub Windows client v 2.13.2.4?

Comment: When I first cloned, I forgot to Fork first.  After that, I forked and then cloned to the same folder (wanted to see if Github Windows would warned me) after which it A) overwrote all my previous files/changes (not yet pushed, unpushed?) and B) created two repositories in the left frame both named "octocat/Spoon-Knife" but one opens to my repository/Spoon-Knife.  So I suspect that GitHub Windows became corrupted and now thinks my repository is pointing to octocat/Spoon-Knife.

Comment: And now the Github Windows client won't even open.  Apparently this has been an issue since 2013.  https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2006    

So I am guessing that the Github Windows client is unreliable and I should use the command line.  Okay.